# Java Stream - Not Calculating total count and total sum for Map List with filtering and grouping process

Tags: java, list, collections, java-stream

I want to get a DTO result after implementing different kinds of filtering and grouping by with Java Stream feature.

Here is the list stored as a Map<String,Student>

```
Id     Type   Value      Date
sId1   BONUS  10       1-1-2022
sId1   OUT    20       2-1-2022
sId1   IN     100      3-1-2022
sId1   OTHER  "other"  4-1-2022
sId1   BONUS  10       1-2-2022
sId2   OUT    20       2-2-2022
sId3   IN     100      3-2-2022
sId2   BONUS  10       4-2-2022
sId2   OUT    20       1-3-2022
sId2   IN     100      2-3-2022
....
```

I want to get this result shown below after I only need the total sum except for OTHER tag and total count as Student

```
month -  Total Value - Total Student
1           230             1 (Only sId1)
2           140             3 (sId1,sId2 and sId3)
3           120             1 (Only sId1)
```

Here is my Studeny Class shown below

```java
public class Student {
   private String id;
   private State type;
   private Object value;
   private LocalDate date;
}
```

Here is the State as enum

```java
public enum State {
    BONUS, IN, OUT, OTHER
}
```

Here is my result DTO class shown below.

```java
public class ResultDto {
    private int month;
    private BigDecimal totalValue;
    private int totalStudents;
}
```

Here is the groupmetric class shown below for **count** and **sum**

```java
public class PersonGroupMetric {

    public static final PersonGroupMetric EMPTY = new PersonGroupMetric(0, 0);

    private int count;
    private int sum;

    public PersonGroupMetric(int count, int sum) {
        this.count = count;
        this.sum = sum;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public int getSum() {
        return sum;
    }

    public void setSum(int sum) {
        this.sum = sum;
    }

    public PersonGroupMetric(Student e) {
        this(1, Integer.parseInt(e.getValue().toString()));
    }

    public PersonGroupMetric add(PersonGroupMetric other) {
        return new PersonGroupMetric(
                this.count + other.count,
                this.sum + other.sum
        );
    }
}
```

I followed this steps to handle with that.

**1 )** Filter only BONUS, OUT and IN from the map.

```java
Map<Integer, PersonGroupMetric> group  = students.values().stream()
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .filter(s -> s.getType() == State.BONUS  || s.getType() == State.IN
                        || s.getType() == OUT)
```

**2 )** Grouping By month to calculate the results.

```java
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    e -> e.getEventDate().getMonthValue(),Collectors.reducing(
                            PersonGroupMetric.EMPTY,
                            PersonGroupMetric::new,
                            PersonGroupMetric::add
                    )

 ));
```

**3 )** Map Object to Dto

```java
var fin = res.entrySet().stream()
    .map(n -> new Dto(
           n.getKey(),
           new BigDecimal(n.getValue().getSum()),
           n.getValue().getCount()
)).collect(toList());

fin.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Here is the result shown below after **fin** result.

```
month -  Total Value - Total Student
1           230             3
2           140             3
3           120             2
```

There is a problem in Total student count. How can I fix it?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Ok. Thank you for reminding it to me. I edited my post.

Comment: Maybe `value` property should be of type `BigDecimal`. Otherwise, you would need to perform a cast.

Comment: BTW, since you're converting `BigDecimal` into `int` in the `PersonGroupMetric`, maybe it should be `int` in the first place. Or a `BigDecimal` everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

In order to obtain the count of unique `Students` (i.e. having distinct ids) per every month, while accumulating the data you can maintain a `Set`  in the Collector and offer `id` of each consumed Student to the set.

To minimize the changes, you can make use of the Java 12 Collector `teeing()` and provide it as a downstream collector of `groupingBy()`.

[`teeing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction)) expects three arguments: two downstream Collectors, and a function that that generates the resulting value based on the partial results produced by each Collector.

As the first downstream, we can provide a combination of Collectors [`mapping()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) + `toSet()` which would be responsible for maintaining a `Set` of `id`s. And the second downstream would be collector reducing from your code.

The *merger* function would generate an instance of `ResultDto` based on set size and `PersonGroupMetric` produced by Collector `reducing()`.

That would require making one change in `PersonGroupMetric`, namelly adding `month` field.

```
public static class PersonGroupMetric {
    public static final PersonGroupMetric EMPTY = new PersonGroupMetric(0, BigDecimal.ZERO, -1);
    
    private int count;
    private BigDecimal sum;
    private int month;
    
    
    // all-args constructor, getters
    
    public PersonGroupMetric(Student e) {
        this(1, e.getValue(), e.getEventDate().getMonthValue());
    }
    
    public PersonGroupMetric add(PersonGroupMetric other) {
        return new PersonGroupMetric(
            this.count + other.count,
            this.sum.add(other.sum),
            this.month
        );
    }        
}
```

And when bring the pieces together, that's how the stream might look like:

```
List<ResultDto> result = students.values().stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .filter(s -> s.getType() == State.BONUS || s.getType() == State.IN
                || s.getType() == State.OUT)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        e -> e.getEventDate().getMonthValue(),
        Collectors.teeing(
            Collectors.mapping(Student::getId, Collectors.toSet()),
            Collectors.reducing(
                PersonGroupMetric.EMPTY,
                PersonGroupMetric::new,
                PersonGroupMetric::add
            ),
            (set, metric) -> new ResultDto(
                metric.getMonth(),
                metric.getSum(),
                set.size() // the number of unique ids
            )
        )
    ))
    .values().stream().toList();
```